# Why are direct Pancakeswap external calls always reverted?

Tags: solidity, remix, bsc

https://bscscan.com/address/0x70f01321cb37a37d4b095bbda7e4bf46e1c9f1f9#code

```
address(0x70f01321CB37A37D4b095bBda7E4BF46E1C9F1F9)
.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("burn(address)", address(myAddress)));
```

}

Any resources would be helpful.

Comment: Do you have an example transaction where it fails?

Comment: The code above, I'm exploring how the pcs pair contract is protected from low-level attacks since the external functions don't seem to have any protection. Is the code above wrong or is there a protection prebuilt in, I'm not seeing.

This is the failed transaction, very non-descript:
[link](https://bscscan.com/tx/0x0743ea285f6e8832c1c3020ff4bd8381a78cfd4cd29d0cd836957e5d726651a4)

Comment: The transaction failed with out of gas, can you try increasing the gas limit?

Comment: I've tried increasing the gas but even with sufficient gas it gets reverted  . any ideas what to try next? should I be testing my own pcs deployment on testnet, and try to make claims on it that way?

Comment: Sorry, but there's not enough information for debugging. If you look at the `burn` function in the `PancakePair` contract the error seems to be between `_mintFee` and the call to `_safeTransfer(_token0, to, amount0)`. It seems serious because it consumes all available gas.